# Sharing an AWS managed KMS key with another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I have an s3 folder that has encrypted objects in it. It is encrypted with the AWS KMS managed keys, not a custom key. I need another AWS account to be able to copy files from this bucket. From what I can tell, I can't share this KMS key across accounts. I also can't easily change this bucket to use custom keys as there are implications with customers. Are there any know good work arounds here?

Comment: how about copy to another s3 where you encrypt with another kms which you can share..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some **experimentation** on two of my accounts.

I found out that by using **bucket policies**, you can enable access to other account only for:

- bucket/object with no encryption
- AES256 encryption which is managed by AWS owned key.

However, if you use AWS Managed CMK,  bucket policy is NOT suited.

Instead,  you can **enable access** to your bucket and objects using [cross-account roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html). I **verified** that it works.

#### Account A

In the Acc A (one with the bucket with `AWS-KMS` encryption, I **created a role** called `kmss3bucket`:

- trust policy - Acc B (which will assume the role and access the objects)
- AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess managed policy
- inline policy for AWS/S3 KMS key:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "kms:Decrypt",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:xxxxxx:key/b811de9a-150a-4d89-8a9a-03e1b878737d"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Accpunt B

A user in Acc B assumes the role, using STS:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/kmss3bucket --role-session-name cross-account-s3
```

This will generate new temp aws credentials. Using the credentials, Acc B will be able to copy the objects from Acc A encrypted with AWS-KMS.